# replacement with sed does not work correctly

Tags: bash, sed, cat

I tried following commands and explain my problem:

```
$cat __sphlist__
signals/APASCI/algi0/algi0.sph
signals/APASCI/ancl0.sph
signals/APASCI/anpe0.sph
signals/APASCI/cepe0.sph
```

why the following command not working, and show content of signals! :

```
$cat __sphlist__ | while read f; do sed 's/signals/nb-signals/'  $f; done
```

but same for echo works?

```
$cat __sphlist__ | while read f; do echo  $f; done
```

I changed sed command like below and it works, I wanted to know what is the difference?

```
$cat __sphlist__ | sed 's/signals/nb-signals/' | while read f; do echo $f ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

you should make sed work on file `sphlist` instead of the lines in that file as input. So:

```
sed 's/signals/nb-&/' sphlist
```

should do.

If you want to change the content of the file, add `-i` (gnu sed)

Answer (score 1):

First of, the entire command can be replaced by the solution of [Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52532363/8344060).

Now to answer your question:

> Why the following command not working, and show the content of signals!
>
> ```
> cat __sphlist__ | while read f; do sed 's/signals/nb-signals/'  $f; done
> ```

This is not a problem with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) but with your understanding of [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) expects to receive a filename as input and will do all its operations on that file. This implies if the variable `f` has a string which matches a filename (which for the first line equals `signals/APASCI/algi0/algi0.sph`), [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) will perform its substitution on that file and hence print its content. If `$f` does not match a file, it will fail.

The command you wrote is equivalent to:

```
sed 's/signals/nb-signals/' signals/APASCI/algi0/algi0.sph
sed 's/signals/nb-signals/' signals/APASCI/ancl0.sph
sed 's/signals/nb-signals/' signals/APASCI/anpe0.sph
sed 's/signals/nb-signals/' signals/APASCI/cepe0.sph
```

We do not know what your intentions are, but it looks like you wanted to rename the directory-name `signals` into `nb-signals`. Here are several ways to correct your script:

- Use `echo` in a pipeline and let [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) read from `/dev/stdin`

  ```
    while read -r f; do echo "$f" | sed 's/signals/nb-signals/'; done < __sphlist__
  ```
- Use a here-string as input for [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

  ```
    while read -r f; do sed 's/signals/nb-signals/' <<< "$f"; done < __sphlist__
  ```
- Use bash-substitution

  ```
    while read -r f; do echo "${f/signals/nb-signals}"; done < __sphlist__
  ```
- Just use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

  ```
    sed 's/signals/nb-signals/' __sphlist__
  ```

**note:** Never use `cat` for looping a file!

Answer (score 0):

[How SED works.](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Execution-Cycle.html#Execution-Cycle)

SED can work with all the lines in a file one by one & hence you don't have to feed SED each line with a WHILE.

```
$cat sphlist | while read f; do sed 's/signals/nb-signals/' $f; done
```

In the above, SED sees $f as a file. Since there is no file like that you get "No such file or directory" error.

```
$cat sphlist | while read f; do echo $f; done
```

Nothing special in the above command as you're reading line by line & printing them.

```
$cat sphlist | sed 's/signals/nb-signals/' | while read f; do echo $f ; done
```

In the above you're passing the CAT result to SED which you could directly do like below

```
sed 's/signals/nb-signals/' sphlist
```

And then you're passing the result of SED to WHILE which prints line by line. The above is only all you need.

```
sed 's/signals/nb-signals/g' sphlist
```

Notice the 'g' in the last of SED in the above command ? that's for a global replacement of values in a file.